# apscheduler BackgroundScheduler() process is not running in the background

Tags: python, linux, logging, click, apscheduler

I am working on a project.
Below are the files from which the problem resides.

[image: package structure]

**cli.py**

```
import click
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)

def func():
    print("scheduler running with interval....")

@click.command()
@click.option('--interval', type=int, default=5, help='Interval for the scheduler in seconds')
def start_scheduler(interval):
    scheduler.add_job(func, 'interval', seconds=interval)
    scheduler.start()
    try:
        # Keep the script running (use Ctrl+C to stop it)
        while True:
            pass
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        scheduler.shutdown()


@click.command()
def stop_scheduler():
        if scheduler.running:
            scheduler.shutdown()
            print("scheduler shut down")
        else:
            print("scheduler is not running")
        
@click.command()
def status_scheduler():
    if scheduler.running:
        print("Scheduler is running.")
    else:
        print("Scheduler is not running.")
```

**setup.py**

```
""" This file is used for packaging the source code and command line interface"""

from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='test_package',
    version='0.1.0',
    packages=['my_pack'],
    install_requires=['click','APScheduler'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'start = my_pack.cli:start_scheduler'
            'status = my_pack.cli:status_scheduler',
            'stop = my_pack.cli:stop_scheduler',
        ],
    },
)
```

**Output i am getting :**

when i run `start` command on terminal it's not running in the background.
to exit from the the script need to hit `ctl+C`
i am using virtual environment in Ubuntu.

**Expected output :**

when i give start command it should return me shell to type another commands and should run in the background until it's stopped manually.

```
$ start
$
```

python version : Python 3.10.12

Platform : #40~22.04.1-Ubuntu

Comment: What is you train of thought that led you to believe that the scheduler would keep running even after Python has exited?

Comment: @AlexGrönholm I don't believe the scheduler would run after Python exits. However, my requirement is to run a specific function every 1 minute in the background on Linux using Python and i must be able to stop that process from command line using another python function command.

Comment: Between we can make Parent process to exit using `os._exit(0)` without killing child process but i know that's not the good way, still searching for better way to do that.

Comment: How did you intend the "stop" command to work, as launching the tool again would not see the variables in the other process which runs the scheduler?

Also, you should be using `BlockingScheduler` instead of `BackgroundScheduler` if you intend to run the scheduler in the foreground like this. The busy-wait loop you have as `while True: pass` will eat of 100% CPU time.

Comment: @AlexGrönholm Thank you so much for the tip to use `BlockingScheduler` it solved my lagging issue. please suggest me any way to achieve my requirements `$ start` , `$ status` , `$ stop`

Comment: You probably want to use your operating system's service manager for that. What OS are you targeting with this?

Comment: Initially i thought to make platform independent but now by understanding complexity i am targeting `Linux` based OS for now.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably make this into a [systemd unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.unit.html). That lets you start and stop the scheduler process at will (using `systemctl start myservice` or `systemctl stop myservice`, respectively), in addition to allowing you to start it at system boot time.

One alternative would be to use [systemd timers](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-schedule-tasks-with-systemd-timers-in-linux) instead, if you just want to run a Python script every minute and it doesn't have a lot of startup overhead. Then you wouldn't need APScheduler either.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comment your motto :

> However, my requirement is to run a specific function every 1 minute in the background on Linux using Python and i must be able to stop that process from command line using another python function command.

To be an answer for that : You can use subprocess to fulfill your expectation by piping out your current python file. So the another file will be still running in background. I just re-created your tree path and explained below,

[image]

**setup.py**

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "my_pack/cli.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

***Note :** Above code will run your cli.py file as subprocess and pipe out the output or error into background.*

**cli.py**

```
import time
while True:
    print('Running in background..')
    time.sleep(5*60)
```

***Note :** Above code as cli.py file made for example to run every 5 minutes a function (print function shown as example) as OP asked for.*

**Result,**

[image]

In the result picture, you can see, before running `setup.py` there is no `cli.py` running in background. After running `setup.py` checking running process using same command `ps aux | grep python3` you can notice `cli.py` is running in background, at the same time `setup.py` is already end its process.

**command used to check all python running process,**

```
ps aux | grep python3
```

**ps** : process status
**a** : all users on system
**u** : display detailed information from user
**x** : add extra information other than terminal process
**grep** : used to search for particular word
**python3** : keyword searching for (process what we looking for)

**To Kill the process**

kill <process_id>
kill 9349

***Simply call this bash line from your python code to kill your `cli.py` using its process id. Process id : `9349` is from my side, it will be vary from your end. Look the result image carefully for better understanding, Hope your expectation fulfilled.***

Note : Focus on 3rd line in process status from result image above to identify `cli.py` process running in background after running `setup.py`.